# Best free collaboration tool now that Google Wave is no more?

Tags: collaboration, google-wave

With the unfortunate demise of Google Wave what is the best alternative free project collaboration tool that you use for your side projects and non-funded software start-ups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is my first choice:

http://www.teamlab.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sign up with Runby, which integrates a Google Wave approach (hosted conversation) with email:

http://runby.me